# Elementary solution to the Mordell equation $y^2=x^3+9$?

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, mordell-curves

I've recently been wondering how to solve the equation of mordell for $k=9$, namely:

$y^{2}=x^{3}+9.$

It reduced to solving the Thue equation $\lvert\,a^{2}-2b^{3}\rvert=3.$ Interestingly, the equation has several solutions (albeit finitely many, since it is a Thue equation). For instance, $253^{2}=40^{3}+9$ is the biggest one I've found. Can we solve it by somewhat elementary means? I know Tzanakis and de Weger have a method bounding a and b, but I Wanted a clean solutions. Also, if anyone knows where I can find a proof for $k=-17$ (I think it was Nagell who solved it), please post a link in the comments.

Comment: E_+00009: r = 1   t = 3   #III =  1
          E(Q) = <(-2, 1)> x <(0, 3)>
          R =   0.8146954406
          10 integral points
            1. (0, 3) = (0, 3)
            2. (0, -3) = -(0, 3)
            3. (-2, 1) = 1 * (-2, 1)
            4. (-2, -1) = -(-2, 1)
            5. (3, 6) = (0, -3) - 1 * (-2, 1)
            6. (3, -6) = -(3, 6)
            7. (6, 15) = (0, -3) + 1 * (-2, 1)
            8. (6, -15) = -(6, 15)
            9. (40, 253) = -2 * (-2, 1)
           10. (40, -253) = -(40, 253)

Comment: So it really is the biggest solution.Is there any way to solve it without elliptic curves?

Comment: I wouldn't know for sure. Given the amount of effort that goes into integer points on elliptic curves, I suggest it is hard to find them all, perhaps also hard to prove that no elementary trick will do the job, since some Mordell curves fall to completely elementary tricks.

Comment: It's curious, because I know that Nagell solved the equation for k=-17, giving a total of 16 solutions and he didnt resort to elliptic curves, so I bet one can solve this one in a similar manner.Sadly, I cannot find the paper with the proof.

Comment: @user211570 Please ask a new question for $k=-17$.

Comment: @WillJagy : for $c=+9=+3^2$ or in general: $c=d^2$ being a square I think this reduces to the problem of finiteness of solutions for the perfect powers because we can always write $(y-d)(y+d)=x^3$ and have that the two factors on the lhs have distance $2d$ and have defined and small common factors (usually $2$ and $d$) - so all other involved factors must be perfect third powers. I have not enough concentration at the moment to finish my scribbles but I've put them at https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9386 where it remains for a short time. Perhaps I can come back to this later.