# Bounding $x^2+6x$ between consecutive cubes when solving $y^3=x^2+6x$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, polynomials, diophantine-equations, mordell-curves

I am familiar with the method of bounding a polynomial between consecutive squares to prove it is not a square. For example, this method can prove $y^2=x^2+x+1$ has no solutions since $x^2<x^2+x+1<(x+1)^2$. The question is how can this method of bounding be applied to a diophantine equation such as $y^3=x^2+6x$? What would be the method for finding the bounds for this type of equation?

Comment: Do you know if these bounds exist? The cubic equation you wrote down is an elliptic curve ; these have incredibly rich structure, and at first glance it is not clear to me if it has integer solutions or not.

Comment: Setting $x+3=a$ gives $y^3=a^2-9$, which is called a Mordell curve.

Comment: $y^3 = x^2 + 6 x$ does have positive integer solutions: $ [3, 3], [12, 6], [250, 40]$.

Comment: This question concerns the same equation: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199967

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it can help for this one: $x$ is near $y^{3/2}$, but that won't generally be an integer.  If it was $y^3 = x^3 + 6 x$, on the other hand, you'd be able to do something...