# Looking for a general method for this type/class of Diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

I have the following

**Conjecture:** If $w$ and $z$ are non-negative integers satisfying the equation
$$
w(w+6) = z(16z^2+36z+27),  \tag{$\star$}
$$
then $w=z=0$.

I believe it to be true for the following two reasons:

1. It is a reformulation of a known result. (*n.b.* I don't want to share the original result here, to avoid influencing answers.)
2. I've done computer verification for all $w,z < 10000$

What are some methods of attack on this type of question? Ideally, I'm looking for a descent-type method, by which I can show that $w=0$ or $z=0$ [or both] or $w=z$ [which would evidently force $w=z=0$].

**EDIT:** Here's the kind of thing I'm playing with…

Let $w=ab$ and $w+6=cd$ for positive integers $a,b,c,d$. Then ($\star$) implies $z=ac$ and $16z^2+36z+27=bd$. Now obviously $cd-ab=6$, which has a general solution; I could plug in that solution and hack away to try to show that $ab=0$. Also, it's trivial that $16a^2c^2 + 36ac + 27 = bd$. But so far, the effort this approach requires seems too inelegant for my taste.

Comment: First observation you can always try to gather "powers" of the variables in order to get some known equations like Pell equation or Fermat's equation, for example if you take $x=w+3$ and $y=4z+3$ you will get:$$4x^2=y^3+9 $$ and this equation is called Mordell's Equation

Comment: @Elaqqad: Well, that's the "original result" I derived this from… so that won't help too much. But thanks!

Comment: The original equation on itself is i the best form because you can see how it factorizes and in which field you can study it. I mean the original form is the natural way of tackling these type of problems

Comment: The original equation apparently requires Skolem's method to solve, and I'm looking for a more elementary solution. So, modulo not finding that solution, I'm going to respectfully disagree that it's the best form.

Comment: The problem of finding elementary ways to solve hard problems is as hard as proving that there are no elementary ways. So I can't claim that there is no  elementary way to solve the equation. Maybe it's not the best form for you and you will come up with a new method but for mathematicians it's the natural way  of studying this equation. The same question was already asked here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1199967/elementary-solution-to-the-mordell-equation-y2-x39

Comment: I don't see why $abcd = z(16z^2 + 36z + 27)$ and ($\star$) implies $z=ac$. Why can't $z=acd$ or other combinations?

Comment: @PluckyBird: Because you can simply redefine $ac=a'$ and $d=c'$ and then $z=a'c'$ (which can then be rewritten as $z=ac$). There’s no restriction on which factors are in $a$ or $c$, until later in the process.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to find integer points on an elliptic curve - this is a much studied problem, see, for example: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/7907/how-to-find-all-integer-points-on-an-elliptic-curve