# Tough Mordell equation $x^3+9=y^2$

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, diophantine-equations, elliptic-curves, mordell-curves

Solve the Mordell equation $x^3+9=y^2$ in integers. It's evident that $(-2,1), (0,3), (3,6), (6,15)$ are solutions, but is there a good way to find all solutions to this equation? 
I have already tried basic ideas from number theory, such as rewriting it as $(y−3)(y+3)=x^3$. Note that $\gcd(y−3,y+3)=1,2,3,6$. For $1$, I have verified there are no solution. For 2, I have gotten one solution, $(−2,1)$. The case for $3$ is quite difficult. If you consider an elliptic curve, I was looking at aspects of its rank, and how it may lead to a solution.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it was asked a few minutes ago, possibly deleted. There was also an earlier identical question.

Comment: This identical question contained only a link that doesn't work. It doesn't give a full solution. Can anyone provide a full solution?

Comment: This one I have denoted a favorite, I will be able to find it if deleted.

Comment: This equation has [10 solutions](http://oeis.org/A001014/a001014.txt) in the integers.

Comment: E_+00009: r = 1   t = 3   #III =  1
          E(Q) = <(-2, 1)> x <(0, 3)>
          R =   0.8146954406
          10 integral points
            1. (0, 3) = (0, 3)
            2. (0, -3) = -(0, 3)
            3. (-2, 1) = 1 * (-2, 1)
            4. (-2, -1) = -(-2, 1)
            5. (3, 6) = (0, -3) - 1 * (-2, 1)
            6. (3, -6) = -(3, 6)
            7. (6, 15) = (0, -3) + 1 * (-2, 1)
            8. (6, -15) = -(6, 15)
            9. (40, 253) = -2 * (-2, 1)
           10. (40, -253) = -(40, 253)

Comment: Is there any full solution or can you just find the solutions via computer?

Comment: Neither one. There is no elementary solution. The site quoted uses elliptic curves.  Thus, there is also no elementary computer solution.

Comment: The link to the site on the other answer doesn't work for me. Could you try reposting the link?

Comment: @Sam FWIW, this [graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x2x5kzja09) has points where there is a solution. You can zoom out or scroll to see there is no solution $40<x<3330$.

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1199967 .

Answer (score 0):

$y^2 = x^3+9\tag{1}$
Using online Magma calculator as follows.

$E$:=EllipticCurve($[0, 0, 0, 0, 9]$);
IntegralPoints($E$);

It says that all integral points are $ [ (-2 : -1 : 1), (0 : 3 : 1), (3 : 6 : 1), (6 : -15 : 1), (40 : 253 : 1) ]$.
Hence all integral point are $(x,y)=(-2,\pm1),(0,\pm3),(3,\pm6),(6,\pm15),(40,\pm253).$